# Can OData controller contains REST methods?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've created OData 4 controller in Web API 2 that looks like this:

```
public class BooksController : ODataController
{
    private ICollection<Book> books;

    public BooksController()
    {
        this.books = new Collection<Book>()
        {
            new Book() { Id = "1", Title = "B1", Price = new Money(1, "EUR") },
            new Book() { Id = "2", Title = "B2", Price = new Money(2, "EUR") }
        };
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Book> Get()
    {
        return this.books.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I want to create regular REST method like this one:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(("api/books"))]
public IEnumerable<Book> GetAll([FromUri] PaginationDto paginationDto)
{
...
}
```

First method is accessible requesting `/odata/Books`. Response contains data according to the OData specification.
Second method (should be) accessible by requesting `/api/books`. Response should contains standard JSON array of PLU objects.

How could I achieve this?

Either I'm able to create pure OData controller or regular REST controller (deriving from ApiController) that unfortunatelly does not comply OData standard when requesting OData route `/odata/Books`.

Comment: You should be able to create a another controller inheriting from ApiController to contain just the non-OData operations. Does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that involves creation of a regural controller containing all the non OData methods, regular OData controller and a custom HTTP controller selector for this OData controller, because these are is posfixed with **ODataController**.